# Infinite Invisibility on Entities (Minecraft)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm looking to summon an entity with a **truly** infinite lasting invisibility effect. Even with having a huge Duration amount (for ActiveEffects), the entity seems to eventually loses invisibility.

I'd rather not use clocks to keep them invisible.

Thanks, let me know if you have questions about my question.

(Note: The entity I hope to keep invisible forever is a Villager)

Comment: If the invisibility ends, you either did something wrong or you have a server running nonstop since 2014.

Answer (score 2):

There is no command that gives an entity eternal invisibility, the exception being the armorstand, which has an nbt tag called `invisible`. In order to keep an entity invisible, you can give it a scoreboard tag by adding following nbt to your summon command:

```
{Tags:["invisible"]}
```

You can then use a repeating command block to give every entity with this tag invisibility using following target selector: `@e[tag=invisible]`

This is assuming that you use the latest release version, which is 1.12.2 at the moment of writing